# ef core slow Initialization of DbContext on a small datamodel

Tags: performance, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I think I have an issue with the initialization of my DbContext. I know a lot of people talked about it but I'm probably doing something wrong because these answers were related to big context or big tables (many columns or a lot of data).

In my case the User table is composed of 30 columns and I have only 30 000 rows.

When I start the application or when it's recycled it took 22 seconds to have the first result of the query.

I've added some logs and from what I understood apparently the query is not the problem (you can find these logs lower). When I copy paste the query in SSMS I have a result in less than one second. After the first execution the query and everything is almost "immediate". So,tThe problem would come from the initialization of the context.

I read that with some precompiled view or this kind of stuff it could be faster. I'm really surprised that with just that "little" table I would need special treatments to have acceptable performance. That's why I think I'm missing something.

My application is in .net core 3.1 and I use Entity Framework Core 5.0.8

In my ConfigureService I have:

```
services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(serviceConfiguration.ConnectionString));
```

My DbContext:

```
public class DbContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly ILoggingService<DbContext> _loggingService;
    private readonly ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;

    public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    public DbContext(DbContextOptions<DbContext> options, ILoggingService<DbContext> loggingService, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        : base(options)
    {
        _loggingService = loggingService;
        _loggerFactory = loggerFactory;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
        optionsBuilder.EnableServiceProviderCaching();

        optionsBuilder.UseLoggerFactory(_loggerFactory);
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        _loggingService.LogError("Begin model creating");
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(u => u.UserId);
            entity.ToTable("User");
        });
        _loggingService.LogError("End model creating");
    }
}
```

> 2021-08-09 15:28:30.830|WARN|Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation|Sensitive data logging is enabled. Log entries and exception messages may include sensitive application data; this mode should only be enabled during development.|url:|action:UsersController.CreateUser

> 2021-08-09 15:28:30.957|INFO|Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure|Entity Framework Core 5.0.8 initialized 'DbContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: SensitiveDataLoggingEnabled |url:|action:UsersController.CreateUser

> 2021-08-09 15:28:52.702|INFO|Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command|Executed DbCommand (53ms) [Parameters=[@__username_0='' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='"Text"', CommandTimeout='30']
> SELECT TOP(1) [u].[UserId], [u].[Email], [u].[Firstname], [u].[Username]
> FROM [User] AS [u]
> WHERE ([u].[Username] = @__username_0) AND ([u].[StatusId] > 0)|url:|action:UsersController.CreateUser

> 2021-08-09 15:28:52.973|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker|Executed action UsersController.CreateUser in 23053.3706ms|url:|action:UsersController.CreateUser

Comment: Have you profiled the application to see where the time is spent?

Comment: There's really too many unknowns here. It could just be that you have a very slow machine.

Comment: "From what I understood the Query is not the problem".  EF Core generally won't initialise the context until you try to use it for something; all I can see from the logs is it took ~22 seconds from when it was actually initialized until it had **finished** running a query;  How have you decided that the query is not the problem?  If you have SQL server locally installed for dev/test you can use Developer edition, which includes SQL Server profiler.  You can use this to see if that SQL statement is actually quite slow, though 30,000 rows is not much.

Comment: I've added some precisions in my question. Like I've precised, it's not related to my machine because after the first lunch it's way faster than the first one so even if my machine would be slow there is still a big difference (1 sec vs 22 sec).
"From what I understood the Query is not the problem" -> When copy/paste the query in SSMS it's always fast. So it's purely related to .net code.

Comment: What happens if you turn off the logging? That may contribute to the one-off initialization cost. The DbContext initialization cost generally depends on the amount of tables / complexity of the schema being initialized which shouldn't be an issue for your example. If something like logging does incur a similar one-off cost then the same "warm up" process should be considered in these cases. (Essentially kick off a simple Count()/Any() query at the earliest initialized point for the application/site.)

Comment: @Gobelet You mean it's very slow the first time it starts, right? After starting, query again, is the speed still so slow?

Comment: @Jason Pan After the first start pr recycle the query is fastest than one second

Comment: @Steve Py the logger write only in files, its serilog. I disabled the write in database to avoid disturtion in my tests

Comment: @Gobelet https://entityframework.net/why-first-query-slow ,this article maybe useful to you.

Comment: @Jsaon Pan I'm using ef core not EF 6 so there are no Cached DbModelStore nor Pre-compiled Views

Comment: After more analysis the problem also appeared after 5-10min of inactivity even if in IIS the idle time is to 0. I've discovered the parameter Min Pool Size in the connection string and it solved my issue for the inactivity of 5-10min. If someone knows more about it and have some cons don't hesitate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more analysis the problem also appeared after 5-10min of inactivity even if in IIS the idle time is to 0. I've discovered the parameter Min Pool Size in the connection string and it solved my issue for the inactivity of 5-10min.